# java regex match any integer or double then replace non number/decimal characters

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to match a string to any integer or double then, if it does not match, I want to remove all invalid characters to make the string a valid integer or double (or empty string). So far, this is what I have but it will print 15- which is not valid

```
String anchorGuyField = "15-";

if(!anchorGuyField.matches("-?\\d+(.\\d+)?")){ //match integer or double
        anchorGuyField = anchorGuyField.replaceAll("[^-?\\d+(.\\d+)?]", ""); //attempt to replace invalid chars... failing here
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Pattern()` and `Matcher()` to validate if string is suitable for covertion to int or double:

```
public class Match{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String anchorGuyField = "asdasda-15.56757-asdasd";

        if(!anchorGuyField.matches("(-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?)")){ //match integer or double
            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?)");
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(anchorGuyField);
            if(matcher.find()){
            anchorGuyField = anchorGuyField.substring(matcher.start(),matcher.end());
            }
        }
        System.out.println(anchorGuyField);
    }
}
```

with:

```
anchorGuyField = anchorGuyField.replaceAll("[^-?\\d+(.\\d+)?]", "");
```

you actually delete content you wanted to match from string, insted of `15` from `15-`, you should get just `-`

Comment: @peggy there was a mistake in regex, it should be `(-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?)` not `(-?\\d+(.\\d+)?)` because if you did't use `\.` it will also mach strings like: 45a43, etc. As `.` in regex match everything, and `\.` only `.` character

Comment: perfect thank you. can you provide some explanation of " anchorGuyField = anchorGuyField.substring(matcher.start(),matcher.end());"

Comment: @peggy matcher.start() return index of character from which regex begin to match, matcher.end() retrun the index on which regex ends its match. So you take a substring from start to end of match, by given regex, only what fit to pattern, in this case, the numeric string

Comment: Awesome. Thanks so much for the explanation. Concise and robust.

Answer (score 0):

The negation checks that none of the given character matches. 15- only contains digits or commas, hence nothing matches the second regex. Maybe you could use something else than a regex to filter out characters.

Check first character is either a minus sign or a number, else remove it, then remove all non numbers characters.